# Displaying taxonomy terms outside the loop but TAXONOMY IMAGE is not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to display some terms from the taxonomy artistas from my posts. It goes on my sidebar, outside the loop, to display name, image, link and number of posts. It works just fine, the only problem is the image doesn't work :) Can someone please help me?

PS.: I'm using the plugin taxonomy images to add the artist's thumbnail.

```
<?php $term_list = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'artistas', 'taxonomy-images-get-terms'); $processed_terms=array();
    foreach ($term_list as $term)
    {
    if (!empty($term->image_id))
    {
    $image_src=wp_get_attachment_image_src($term->image_id,'archive-thumbnail');
    $image_src=$image_src[0];
    }
    else
    {
    $image_src='http://sites.dammit.com.br/2016dmt/files/2017/08/camila-150x150.jpg';
    }

    $processed_terms[]=array(
    'name'=>$term->name,
    'description'=>$term->description,
    'url'=>get_term_link($term),
    'image'=>$image_src,
    'posts'=>$actual_term_posts,
    'count'=>$term->count,
    'post_count' => 1
    );
    }
    foreach ($processed_terms as $term) {
    echo "<div class='col-md-6 col-sm-4 col-xs-2 artista-index'>
    <a href='{$term['url']}' title='{$term['name']}'><img src='{$term['image']}' alt='{$term['name']}' class='effect8'></a>
    <div class='reviews' style='text-align:right;'>{$term['count']} ".($term['count']==1?'review':'reviews')."</div>
    <small class='nome'>
    <a href='{$term['url']}' title='{$term['name']}'>{$term['name']} <i class='fa fa-chevron-right'></i></a>
    </small>
    </div>";
    } ?>
```

Comment: You are still using `$term['image']`  for the image source, instead of your ` $image_src` variable

Comment: Why your playing with two loop ? While you can do it with single loop. According to me it is wrong practice it takes more time to fetch the data.

Comment: @fluffykitten why he has did like this? Do you get the purpose?

Comment: @Aki The first loop is building up an array with the term info and the the second loop is displaying them. The OP might have code in between that they haven't included that makes it necessary to do it this way. If everything is correct, it should have no bearing on the output.

Comment: Your code looks fine, so the most likely cause if that `wp_get_attachment_image_src ` is not returning anything. You are looking for a custom size `archive-thumbnail` - make sure it is actually defined - if in doubt try using the standard "thumbnail". Secondly, change the code so that if checks the value of `$image_src` after you get it, and if it doesn't have a valid image then set it to use the default image.

Comment: @FluffyKitten it does return. I'm using the same "base code" to run the same thing on my index and it works just fine!

Comment: Have you tried a var_dump or anything to confirm that it *definitely* returns an image url here? You should never assume that something works - always debug it properly to rule it out. Just because it works in one place doesn't mean it will work everywhere - something else could be interfering with the code or there may not be an "archive-thumb" size created for these posts. Also, you should still do the check for an empty value either way, because if it ever does fail you'll get nothing.